# how to get value from web and convert it into integer

Tags: java, selenium

I want to get value from web 
For eg : `Total AMount : 25000`
and want to convert this value into integer to proceed comparision step but after printing `totat_Amt` it displayed as

`"java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "25,000""`

Here is my code :

```
WebElement gt = driver.findElement(By.id("totAmt"));
String total_Amt=gt.toString();
System.out.println("Total Amt:"+total_Amt);
//int total_amt_val =Integer.parseInt(total_Amt);
System.out.println(total_amt_val);
```

Comment: use `String total_Amt=gt.getText();` and post the total_Amt output here. Also post the html fragment.

Answer (score 2):

Try to replace all non-numeric symbols:

```
WebElement gt = driver.findElement(By.id("totAmt"));
String total_Amt = gt.toString(); // "25,000"

// replace 'bad' symbols
String onlyNumbers = total_Amt.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "");  // "25000"

System.out.println("Total Amt: " + total_Amt);
int total_amt_val = Integer.parseInt(onlyNumbers); // 25000
System.out.println(total_amt_val);
```

`\\d` means `all numbers`, `[^\\d]` means `all non-numbers`, and if you want to keep some another symbols, just add them into `[]` — e.g. use `[\\d.]` if you want to keep dots too.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [NumberFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html)

`NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US).parse("25,000").intValue()`  will return `25000`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
WebElement gt = driver.findElement(By.id("totAmt"));
String total_Amt = gt.toString(); // 25,000
total_Amt = total_Amt.replaceAll(",", ""); // removes all ',' -> 25000
int total_amt_val = Integer.parseInt(total_Amt); // 25000 as int already
System.out.println(total_amt_val); // 25000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace all the comma first using `replaceAll` method and then directly parse it as below. additionally, you need to use `getText()` method should be used to retrieve the element text.

```
WebElement gt = driver.findElement(By.id("totAmt"));
//To be changed as gt.getText().
String total_Amt=gt.getText();      
System.out.println("Total Amt:"+total_Amt);
//Replace comma as empty and then you can normal parse the string to int
int total_amt_val =Integer.parseInt(total_Amt.replaceAll(",",""));
System.out.println(total_amt_val)
```

In case , If you are getting the total_Amt value as `Total AMount : 25000`, then extract the amount value using `substring` method and then replace all the , as empty using `replaceAll` method

```
int total_amt_val =Integer.parseInt(total_Amt.substring(total_Amt.indexOf(":")+2).replaceAll(",",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are dealing with price, use this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

       WebElement gt = driver.findElement(By.id("totAmt"));
       String total_Amt = gt.getText(); // total_Amt=25,000.00

       BigDecimal bd_amt = parse(total_Amt , Locale.US); // Use this if the value is price
       int int_amount = parse(total_Amt , Locale.US).intValueExact(); // Use this if you want integer

       System.out.println("Price : " + bd_amt);
       System.out.println("Amount : " + int_amount);
}

private static BigDecimal parse(final String amount, final Locale locale) throws ParseException {
    final NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
    if (format instanceof DecimalFormat) {
        ((DecimalFormat) format).setParseBigDecimal(true);
    }
    return (BigDecimal) format.parse(amount.replaceAll("[^\\d.,]", ""));
}
```

Sample Output:

```
 Price : 25000.00
 Amount : 25000
```